# Need to point dns records to my locally hosted exchange server from godaddy

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, dns

I have a domain in godaddy and would like to host my website in my local server. I don't know the entire process, can someone please help me?

I am using wordpress. In xampp I installed wordpress and run my website locally, I want to point this local site to my domain

I know my question isn't clear,

1. my site is running locally with out any problems
2. am already purchased the domain in Godaddy.
3. I want to link my website with domain name.

I have a Windows 2012 R2 on a dedicated physical server
Installed XAMPP on the server
running my website locally.

What is the procedure for linking my local website with domain name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running it locally make sure you've opened port 80, and make sure your ISP knows you are hosting a web server as they normally require a business plan for large amounts of traffic.

I would suggest getting web hosting or a VPS and make sure you're pointing the **A** record **@** and the **A** record **www** to your IP.

Don't know your IP? Google "what's my IP"

Answer (score 1):

1. Find an IP of your server
2. Configure your domain to point to the IP of your server
3. Setup your server to handle sub-domains properly, if needed, all required rewrites etc.

I hope there must by some help from Godaddy, how to link your IP to your domain name.